# Python counting in a tuple list

Tags: python, list, count, tuples

Basically I have a long list of tuples with author names and a year like here below

```
a =[('Volozhyn AI', 2007),
 ('Lam KL', 2010),
 ('Boudreau NG', 2006),
 ('Tsuchitani M', 1997),
 ('Zheng LP', 1997),
```

The list is much longer, I need to count the times a year occurs in this list, so as output list

```
b = [(1970, x times),
     (1971, y times), etc
```

I found that the function Counter counts all the elements in a list and gives a output like that. However, I can't seem to let Counter only count the years. 
So I have to either make a new list with only the years or another methode. 
Suggestions?

Comment: Have you *tried* to *"make a new list with only the years"*? That's probably the most straightforward approach.

Comment: Can I create that simply out of this list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

a =[('Volozhyn AI', 2007),
 ('Lam KL', 2010),
 ('Boudreau NG', 2006),
 ('Tsuchitani M', 1997),
 ('Zheng LP', 1997)]

b = (Counter(i[1] for i in a)).items()
print b
```

Output:

```
[(2010, 1), (1997, 2), (2006, 1), (2007, 1)]
```

With `i[1] for i in a` you get the *list with only the years* (`[2007, 2010, 2006, 1997, 1997]`). Then, you count them using `Counter` and convert it to a list to fit your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(elem[1] for elem in a)
```

Will give

```
Counter({1997: 2, 2010: 1, 2006: 1, 2007: 1})
```

Above code picks up the second element [index 1] in each element and then counts..

Comment: If you're going to post an answer, it would be good to provide an explanation around it as well. Code dumping is not the best approach.

Comment: Good answers should not only incorporate code, but also an explanation. Please show an example output from your code so OP can see what you're doing here.

Comment: The first revision of this is complete garbage, and even with other people's help you're still not providing a useful explananation

Comment: Rolled back to include that one line. I was trying to format the sample output you gave. Must have overlapped with your edit. However, you should look at the answer that got accepted. There was a full explanation on why the code works the way it does. That is typically what a lot of people are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for enlightening. I will follow next time.